# EtherScan access needed on Test net

Tags: blockchain, solidity, ganache

We are developing application on VS code with Ganache.
So everything will be local as it is Ganache.

As explained in following link, we cannot use etherScan functions if you are using Ganache.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73090/can-etherscan-io-show-local-ganache-transaction-details

Can you please suggest some commonly used test nets available on online where we can connect VS code with test net.
My expection is to access etherScan from that test net if there is a possibility.
Do we really need to pay if we need such service or is there something which is free during development.

I am aware we can use Remix but I want my solidity code to sit in VS code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to any test net like  bsc test net or matic test net and then write in google the testnet name with  faucet they will give you free test token example bsctestnet faucet